# Getting the value from asp:LinkButton's CommandArgument attribute using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, repeater

I need to get the value of the `CommandArgument` attribute of a LinkButton, in an asp:Repeater.

I have an asp:Repeater with 2 LinkButtons whose CommandArgument I set to a value:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="odd">                                        
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "batch_id")%></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productId")%></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "serial_number")%></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "activation_card_number")%></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "transaction_amount","{0:C}")%></td>                                        
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "response_dt", "{0:M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")%></td>                                        
        <td style="text-align:center;"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "resp_process_msg")%></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "resp_response_code")%></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnRestageAdd" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("activation_card_number")%>' runat="server" Text="stage" class="add" OnClientClick="return false;" /></td>                                                                                
        <td style="text-align:center;"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnRestageMinus" CommandName="Subtract" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("activation_card_number")%>' runat="server" Text="stage" class="minus" OnClientClick="return false;" /></td>
      </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have suppressed the PostBack with OnClientClick="return false;" so that I can pop a jQuery dialog modal when the link buttons get clicked:

```
if (btnAdd != null) {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        $("#<%=divDialogAdd.ClientID %>").removeAttr("style");
        $("#<%=divDialogAdd.ClientID %>").dialog("open");
    });
}
```

In the modal I have 2 other asp:LinkButtons, and when the 'Yes' button is clicked I do the postback like so:

```
yesBtn.click(function() {
    setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'btnAdd\',\'\')', 0); //need to add a param
});
```

What I need to do, is somehow grab the CommandArgument value from the LinkButton in the Repeater, so that I can pass that as a parametere or assign it to a hidden field. I have tried jQuery's `attr()`, but that only works when the attribute was set using that function as well. How can I get this value, or what other way can I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get that property in javascript. Because the command argument is passed as the the argument in the doPostBack function. But i think you can change your code like this to decrease the complexity.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnRestageAdd" 
                CommandName="Add" 
                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("activation_card_number")%>' 
                runat="server" 
                Text="stage" 
                class="add" 
                OnClientClick='<%#Eval("activation_card_number","javascript:return YourFunction({0});")%>' />
```

do the stuff that you want to do in the function `YourFunction` return `true` if Yes is pressed and return `false`

Comment: hrmm, when I place the <%#Eval("activation_card_number")%> inside whatever i name the function, i get the server tag is not well formed

Comment: try this..<%#Eval("activation_card_number","javascript:YoutFunction({0});")%>

Comment: OnClientClick='<%#Eval("activation_card_number","Javascript:return RestageAdd(\"{0}\");")%>'      is what works. Thanks for the perfect answer

Comment: I salute you Sir!!